# Devextreme Angular Datagrid Tree Structure

Tags: angular

Now I'm working on an angular `devextreme` `tree-list`. I have a JSON file with data. I want to know how can I assign the data to `devextreme` `dx-tree-list`. Here is the code,

.html-

```html
     <dx-tree-list
                id="gridContainer"
                [dataSource]="onefollowerSource"
                keyExpr="pk"
                parentIdExpr=""
                [showRowLines]="true"
                [showBorders]="true"
                [columnAutoWidth]="true"
                [allowColumnResizing]="true"
                [columnResizingMode]="'nextColumn'"
                [allowColumnReordering]="true">
            <dxo-filter-row [visible]="true"></dxo-filter-row>
            <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true" ></dxo-header-filter>
            <dxo-scrolling mode="virtual"></dxo-scrolling>
    
            <dxi-column dataField="pk" caption="Id"></dxi-column>
              
            <dxi-column dataField="username" caption="Name" dataType="string">
            </dxi-column>
         
            <dxi-column dataField="full_name"></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="biography_with_entities" ></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="is_private"></dxi-column>
    
            <dxi-column dataField="profile_pic_url" cssClass="cell-highlighted" width="200px">
            </dxi-column>
    
            <dxi-column dataField="profile_pic_id"></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="is_verified"></dxi-column>
            <dxi-column dataField="has_highlight_reels" ></dxi-column>
             
            </dx-tree-list>
```

.ts-

```js
import onefollower from '../../../../../assets/json/onefollowers.json';
this.onefollowerSource=onefollower.user;
```

.json-

```json
{
    "user":[ {
        "pk": 47008610225,
        "username": "franklinthomasyi",
        "full_name": "Franklin Yi",
        "is_private": true,
        "profile_pic_url": "https:\/\/instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t51.2885-19\/271669907_291115399702903_8999771527538334124_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s150x150&_nc_ht=instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=-YrgdW7-KwAAX-0sOvp&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8u-9D9TxKNVs9fmb65-vTJfieIr22-CC31Zw6fEnA1Xg&oe=62DE694B&_nc_sid=a9513d",
        "profile_pic_id": "2748471765455187210_47008610225",
        "is_verified": true,
        "follow_friction_type": 0,
        "has_anonymous_profile_picture": false,
        "media_count": 129,
        "geo_media_count": 0,
        "follower_count": 1389,
        "following_count": 1364,
        "following_tag_count": 0,
        "is_supervision_features_enabled": false,
        "biography": "I do comedy and wear a lot of Stone Cold Steve Austin T-Shirts \ud83e\udd78",
        "biography_with_entities": {
            "raw_text": "I do comedy and wear a lot of Stone Cold Steve Austin T-Shirts \ud83e\udd78",
            "entities": []
        },
        "biography_product_mentions": [],
        "external_url": "",
        "show_fb_link_on_profile": false,
        "primary_profile_link_type": 0,
        "total_igtv_videos": 0,
        "has_videos": true,
        "total_clips_count": 1,
        "total_ar_effects": 0,
        "usertags_count": 316,
        "is_favorite": false,
        "is_favorite_for_stories": false,
        "is_favorite_for_igtv": false,
        "is_favorite_for_clips": false,
        "is_favorite_for_highlights": false,
        "live_subscription_status": "default",
        "is_interest_account": true,
        "has_chaining": true,
        "hd_profile_pic_versions": [
            {
                "width": 320,
                "height": 320,
                "url": "https:\/\/instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t51.2885-19\/271669907_291115399702903_8999771527538334124_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s320x320&_nc_ht=instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=-YrgdW7-KwAAX-0sOvp&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT_SU0FdIAtDnx4GHtdPXq51MhXCnYaFqHxU_isT2CxUNQ&oe=62DE694B&_nc_sid=a9513d"
            },
            {
                "width": 640,
                "height": 640,
                "url": "https:\/\/instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t51.2885-19\/271669907_291115399702903_8999771527538334124_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s640x640&_nc_ht=instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=-YrgdW7-KwAAX-0sOvp&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT8Je0FBkvoMb_m6iAS3Q55id-1rTzBEs_utMl1te59Gug&oe=62DE694B&_nc_sid=a9513d"
            }
        ],
        "hd_profile_pic_url_info": {
            "url": "https:\/\/instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t51.2885-19\/271669907_291115399702903_8999771527538334124_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fkiv7-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=107&_nc_ohc=-YrgdW7-KwAAX-0sOvp&edm=AEF8tYYBAAAA&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AT-YsonZHdcVh-DyQ144lfDQ4g94CXJCHdfVRlaKzUhyVQ&oe=62DE694B&_nc_sid=a9513d",
            "width": 756,
            "height": 756
        },
        "mutual_followers_count": 0,
        "profile_context": "",
        "profile_context_links_with_user_ids": [],
        "profile_context_facepile_users": [],
        "has_highlight_reels": true,
        "has_guides": false,
        "show_shoppable_feed": false,
        "shoppable_posts_count": 0,
        "merchant_checkout_style": "none",
        "seller_shoppable_feed_type": "none",
        "num_visible_storefront_products": 0,
        "storefront_attribution_username": null,
        "has_active_affiliate_shop": false,
        "creator_shopping_info": {
            "linked_merchant_accounts": []
        },
        "is_eligible_for_smb_support_flow": false,
        "is_eligible_for_lead_center": false,
        "is_experienced_advertiser": false,
        "lead_details_app_id": "com.bloks.www.ig.smb.services.lead_gen.all_leads",
        "smb_support_partner": null,
        "direct_messaging": "UNKNOWN",
        "fb_page_call_to_action_id": "",
        "is_promotions_in_profile_enabled": true,
        "address_street": "",
        "business_contact_method": "UNKNOWN",
        "category": "Artist",
        "city_id": 0,
        "city_name": "",
        "contact_phone_number": "",
        "is_call_to_action_enabled": false,
        "is_profile_audio_call_enabled": false,
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "public_email": "",
        "public_phone_country_code": "",
        "public_phone_number": "",
        "zip": "",
        "instagram_location_id": "",
        "is_business": true,
        "professional_conversion_suggested_account_type": 2,
        "account_type": 2,
        "can_hide_category": true,
        "can_hide_public_contacts": true,
        "should_show_category": true,
        "should_show_public_contacts": false,
        "interop_messaging_user_fbid": "17847664097562226",
        "bio_links": [],
        "can_add_fb_group_link_on_profile": false,
        "is_facebook_onboarded_charity": false,
        "has_active_charity_business_profile_fundraiser": false,
        "charity_profile_fundraiser_info": {
            "pk": 47008610225,
            "is_facebook_onboarded_charity": false,
            "has_active_fundraiser": false,
            "consumption_sheet_config": {
                "can_viewer_donate": false,
                "currency": null,
                "donation_url": null,
                "privacy_disclaimer": null,
                "donation_disabled_message": "We're having trouble connecting right now. Please try your donation another time.",
                "donation_amount_config": {
                    "donation_amount_selector_values": [],
                    "default_selected_donation_value": null,
                    "minimum_donation_amount": null,
                    "maximum_donation_amount": null,
                    "prefill_amount": null,
                    "user_currency": null
                },
                "you_donated_message": null,
                "profile_fundraiser_id": null,
                "has_viewer_donated": null
            }
        },
        "transparency_product_enabled": false,
        "account_badges": [],
        "pronouns": [],
        "fan_club_info": {
            "fan_club_id": null,
            "fan_club_name": null
        },
        "has_nft_posts": false,
        "include_direct_blacklist_status": true,
        "is_potential_business": false,
        "show_post_insights_entry_point": true,
        "request_contact_enabled": false,
        "remove_message_entrypoint": false,
        "is_bestie": false,
        "show_account_transparency_details": false,
        "auto_expand_chaining": false,
        "is_new_to_instagram": false,
        "highlight_reshare_disabled": false,
        "is_memorialized": false,
        "open_external_url_with_in_app_browser": true,
        "has_exclusive_feed_content": false
    }],
    "status": "ok",
    "unrelated_data": {
        "retry": 0,
        "id_acc": "7346",
        "proxy_info": "\u041c\u043e\u043b\u0434\u043e\u0432\u0430 \u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0430\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439"
    },
    "time_gen": 1.58
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DevExtreme Documaentation](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TreeList/Overview/Angular/Light/) (Guide & Demo) is all you need

html file

```
<dx-tree-list
  id="tasks"
  [dataSource]="tasks"
  keyExpr="Task_ID"
  parentIdExpr="Task_Parent_ID"
  [expandedRowKeys]="[1, 2]"
  [selectedRowKeys]="[1, 29, 42]"
  [columnAutoWidth]="true"
  [wordWrapEnabled]="true"
  [showBorders]="true"
>
  <dxo-search-panel [visible]="true" width="250"></dxo-search-panel>
  <dxo-header-filter [visible]="true"></dxo-header-filter>
  <dxo-selection mode="multiple"></dxo-selection>
  <dxo-column-chooser [enabled]="true"></dxo-column-chooser>

  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Subject" [width]="300"></dxi-column>
  <dxi-column
    dataField="Task_Assigned_Employee_ID"
    caption="Assigned"
    [minWidth]="200"
    cssClass="employee"
    cellTemplate="employeeTemplate"
  >
    <dxo-lookup
      [dataSource]="employees"
      valueExpr="ID"
      displayExpr="Name"
    ></dxo-lookup>
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Status" caption="Status" [minWidth]="100">
    <dxo-lookup [dataSource]="statuses"></dxo-lookup>
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column
    dataField="Task_Completion"
    caption="% Completed"
    [visible]="false"
    [customizeText]="getCompletionText"
  ></dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="Task_Priority" caption="Priority" [visible]="false">
    <dxo-lookup
      [dataSource]="priorities"
      valueExpr="id"
      displayExpr="value"
    ></dxo-lookup>
  </dxi-column>
  <dxi-column
    dataField="Task_Start_Date"
    caption="Start Date"
    dataType="date"
  ></dxi-column>
  <dxi-column
    dataField="Task_Due_Date"
    caption="Due Date"
    dataType="date"
  ></dxi-column>
  <div *dxTemplate="let options of 'employeeTemplate'">
    <div
      class="img"
      *ngIf="options.data.Task_Assigned_Employee"
      style.background-image="url('{{
        options.data.Task_Assigned_Employee.Picture
      }}')"
    ></div>
    <span *ngIf="options.data.Task_Assigned_Employee" class="name">{{
      options.data.Task_Assigned_Employee.Name
    }}</span>
  </div>
</dx-tree-list>
```

ts component

```
import { NgModule, Component, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { DxTreeListModule } from 'devextreme-angular';

import {
  Service, Task, Employee, Priority,
} from './app.service';

if (!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
  enableProdMode();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'demo-app',
  templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
  providers: [Service],
  preserveWhitespaces: true,
})
export class AppComponent {
  tasks: Task[];

  employees: Employee[];

  priorities: Priority[];

  statuses: string[];

  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.tasks = service.getTasks();
    this.employees = service.getEmployees();
    this.priorities = service.getPriorities();

    this.statuses = [
      'Not Started',
      'Need Assistance',
      'In Progress',
      'Deferred',
      'Completed',
    ];
  }

  getCompletionText(cellInfo) {
    return `${cellInfo.valueText}%`;
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DxTreeListModule,
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export class Task {
  Task_ID: number;

  Task_Parent_ID: number;

  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: number;

  Task_Completion: number;

  Task_Priority: number;

  Task_Status: string;

  Task_Subject: string;

  Task_Start_Date: string;

  Task_Due_Date: string;

  Task_Assigned_Employee?: Employee;
}

export class Employee {
  ID: number;

  Name: string;

  Picture: string;
}

export class Priority {
  id: number;

  value: string;
}

const tasks: Task[] = [{
  Task_ID: 1,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Plans 2015',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-01-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-04-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 2,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 2,
  Task_Subject: 'Health Insurance',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-12T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-05-30T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 75,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 3,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 4,
  Task_Subject: 'New Brochures',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-17T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 4,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 31,
  Task_Subject: 'Training',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-02T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-06-29T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 5,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 5,
  Task_Subject: 'NDA',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-12T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-05-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 90,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 6,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 7,
  Task_Subject: 'Revenue Projections',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-24T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-04-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 7,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 9,
  Task_Subject: 'TV Recall',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-04-18T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-02-04T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 90,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 8,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Overtime',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-06-10T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-06-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 9,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 8,
  Task_Subject: 'Recall and Refund Forms',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-06-17T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-09T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 10,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 10,
  Task_Subject: 'Shippers',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-07-10T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-11T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 11,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Hardware Upgrade',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-07-22T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-05-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 95,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 12,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Touch-Enabled Apps',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-08-05T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-30T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 90,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 13,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Online Sales',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-08-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-09-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 14,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'New Website Design',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-09-17T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-11-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 15,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Bandwidth Increase',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-11-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-11-07T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 16,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 18,
  Task_Subject: 'Support',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-11-10T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-11-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 17,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 31,
  Task_Subject: 'Training Material',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-11-14T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-02-05T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 18,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 22,
  Task_Subject: 'New Database',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-12-24T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-12-29T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 95,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 19,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 32,
  Task_Subject: 'New HDMI Specification',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-01-02T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-01-31T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Deferred',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 50,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 20,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 3,
  Task_Subject: 'Automation Server',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-01-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-30T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 85,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 21,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 40,
  Task_Subject: 'Retail Sales',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-01-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-02-10T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 22,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Reports',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-03-13T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-05-07T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 50,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 23,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 5,
  Task_Subject: 'Budget',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-03-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 30,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 24,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 13,
  Task_Subject: 'Shipping Labels',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-04-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 50,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 25,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 10,
  Task_Subject: 'New Warehouse',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-04-05T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 65,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 26,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 10,
  Task_Subject: 'Forklift',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-04-07T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-04-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 20,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 27,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Customer Follow Up Plan',
  Task_Start_Date: '2016-05-05T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2016-05-11T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 40,
  Task_Parent_ID: 0,
}, {
  Task_ID: 28,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 7,
  Task_Subject: 'Prepare 2015 Financial',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-01-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-01-31T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 1,
}, {
  Task_ID: 29,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 4,
  Task_Subject: 'Prepare 2015 Marketing Plan',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-01-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-01-31T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 1,
}, {
  Task_ID: 30,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 2,
  Task_Subject: 'Review Health Insurance Options Under the Affordable Care Act',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-12T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-04-25T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 50,
  Task_Parent_ID: 2,
}, {
  Task_ID: 31,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Choose between PPO and HMO Health Plan',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-04-15T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'In Progress',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 75,
  Task_Parent_ID: 2,
}, {
  Task_ID: 32,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Google AdWords Strategy',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-16T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-28T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 29,
}, {
  Task_ID: 34,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 28,
  Task_Subject: '2015 Brochure Designs',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-19T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-24T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 3,
}, {
  Task_ID: 35,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 29,
  Task_Subject: 'Brochure Design Review',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-19T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-22T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 34,
}, {
  Task_ID: 36,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 29,
  Task_Subject: 'Website Re-Design Plan',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-19T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-24T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 34,
}, {
  Task_ID: 37,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 4,
  Task_Subject: 'Rollout of New Website and Marketing Brochures',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-28T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 3,
}, {
  Task_ID: 38,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 8,
  Task_Subject: 'Update Sales Strategy Documents',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-22T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 29,
}, {
  Task_ID: 39,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 41,
  Task_Subject: 'Create 2012 Sales Report',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-21T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 29,
}, {
  Task_ID: 40,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 42,
  Task_Subject: 'Direct vs Online Sales Comparison Report',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-22T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 29,
}, {
  Task_ID: 41,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 4,
  Task_Subject: 'Review 2012 Sales Report and Approve 2015 Plans',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-02-23T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-02-28T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 29,
}, {
  Task_ID: 42,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 3,
  Task_Subject: 'Deliver R&D Plans for 2015',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-10T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 1,
}, {
  Task_ID: 43,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 32,
  Task_Subject: 'Create 2015 R&D Plans',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-01T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-07T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 42,
}, {
  Task_ID: 44,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 33,
  Task_Subject: '2015 QA Strategy Report',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-02T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-05T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 42,
}, {
  Task_ID: 45,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 31,
  Task_Subject: '2015 Training Events',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-02T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-04T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 4,
}, {
  Task_ID: 46,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 2,
  Task_Subject: 'Non-Compete Agreements',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-12T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-14T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 1,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 5,
}, {
  Task_ID: 47,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 1,
  Task_Subject: 'Update NDA Agreement',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-14T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-16T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 4,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 5,
}, {
  Task_ID: 48,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 5,
  Task_Subject: 'Update Employee Files with New NDA',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-16T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-26T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Need Assistance',
  Task_Priority: 2,
  Task_Completion: 90,
  Task_Parent_ID: 5,
}, {
  Task_ID: 49,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 6,
  Task_Subject: 'Sign Updated NDA',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-25T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 5,
}, {
  Task_ID: 50,
  Task_Assigned_Employee_ID: 7,
  Task_Subject: 'Sign Updated NDA',
  Task_Start_Date: '2015-03-20T00:00:00',
  Task_Due_Date: '2015-03-25T00:00:00',
  Task_Status: 'Completed',
  Task_Priority: 3,
  Task_Completion: 100,
  Task_Parent_ID: 5,
}];

const employees: Employee[] = [{
  ID: 1,
  Name: 'John Heart',
  Picture: 'images/employees/01.png',
}, {
  ID: 2,
  Name: 'Samantha Bright',
  Picture: 'images/employees/04.png',
}, {
  ID: 3,
  Name: 'Arthur Miller',
  Picture: 'images/employees/02.png',
}, {
  ID: 4,
  Name: 'Robert Reagan',
  Picture: 'images/employees/03.png',
}, {
  ID: 5,
  Name: 'Greta Sims',
  Picture: 'images/employees/06.png',
}, {
  ID: 6,
  Name: 'Brett Wade',
  Picture: 'images/employees/05.png',
}, {
  ID: 7,
  Name: 'Sandra Johnson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/08.png',
}, {
  ID: 8,
  Name: 'Ed Holmes',
  Picture: 'images/employees/07.png',
}, {
  ID: 9,
  Name: 'Barb Banks',
  Picture: 'images/employees/09.png',
}, {
  ID: 10,
  Name: 'Kevin Carter',
  Picture: 'images/employees/10.png',
}, {
  ID: 11,
  Name: 'Cindy Stanwick',
  Picture: 'images/employees/15.png',
}, {
  ID: 12,
  Name: 'Sammy Hill',
  Picture: 'images/employees/11.png',
}, {
  ID: 13,
  Name: 'Davey Jones',
  Picture: 'images/employees/12.png',
}, {
  ID: 14,
  Name: 'Victor Norris',
  Picture: 'images/employees/13.png',
}, {
  ID: 15,
  Name: 'Mary Stern',
  Picture: 'images/employees/16.png',
}, {
  ID: 16,
  Name: 'Robin Cosworth',
  Picture: 'images/employees/14.png',
}, {
  ID: 17,
  Name: 'Kelly Rodriguez',
  Picture: 'images/employees/17.png',
}, {
  ID: 18,
  Name: 'James Anderson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/18.png',
}, {
  ID: 19,
  Name: 'Antony Remmen',
  Picture: 'images/employees/19.png',
}, {
  ID: 20,
  Name: 'Olivia Peyton',
  Picture: 'images/employees/20.png',
}, {
  ID: 21,
  Name: 'Taylor Riley',
  Picture: 'images/employees/21.png',
}, {
  ID: 22,
  Name: 'Amelia Harper',
  Picture: 'images/employees/22.png',
}, {
  ID: 23,
  Name: 'Wally Hobbs',
  Picture: 'images/employees/23.png',
}, {
  ID: 24,
  Name: 'Brad Jameson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/24.png',
}, {
  ID: 25,
  Name: 'Karen Goodson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/25.png',
}, {
  ID: 26,
  Name: 'Marcus Orbison',
  Picture: 'images/employees/26.png',
}, {
  ID: 27,
  Name: 'Sandy Bright',
  Picture: 'images/employees/27.png',
}, {
  ID: 28,
  Name: 'Morgan Kennedy',
  Picture: 'images/employees/28.png',
}, {
  ID: 29,
  Name: 'Violet Bailey',
  Picture: 'images/employees/29.png',
}, {
  ID: 30,
  Name: 'Ken Samuelson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/32.png',
}, {
  ID: 31,
  Name: 'Nat Maguiree',
  Picture: 'images/employees/34.png',
}, {
  ID: 32,
  Name: 'Bart Arnaz',
  Picture: 'images/employees/37.png',
}, {
  ID: 33,
  Name: 'Leah Simpson',
  Picture: 'images/employees/38.png',
}, {
  ID: 34,
  Name: 'Arnie Schwartz',
  Picture: 'images/employees/40.png',
}, {
  ID: 35,
  Name: 'Billy Zimmer',
  Picture: 'images/employees/42.png',
}, {
  ID: 36,
  Name: 'Samantha Piper',
  Picture: 'images/employees/30.png',
}, {
  ID: 37,
  Name: 'Maggie Boxter',
  Picture: 'images/employees/31.png',
}, {
  ID: 38,
  Name: 'Terry Bradley',
  Picture: 'images/employees/33.png',
}, {
  ID: 39,
  Name: 'Gabe Jones',
  Picture: 'images/employees/35.png',
}, {
  ID: 40,
  Name: 'Lucy Ball',
  Picture: 'images/employees/36.png',
}, {
  ID: 41,
  Name: 'Jim Packard',
  Picture: 'images/employees/43.png',
}, {
  ID: 42,
  Name: 'Hannah Brookly',
  Picture: 'images/employees/39.png',
}, {
  ID: 43,
  Name: 'Harv Mudd',
  Picture: 'images/employees/44.png',
}, {
  ID: 44,
  Name: 'Clark Morgan',
  Picture: 'images/employees/45.png',
}, {
  ID: 45,
  Name: 'Todd Hoffman',
  Picture: 'images/employees/46.png',
}, {
  ID: 46,
  Name: 'Jackie Garmin',
  Picture: 'images/employees/47.png',
}, {
  ID: 47,
  Name: 'Lincoln Bartlett',
  Picture: 'images/employees/49.png',
}, {
  ID: 48,
  Name: 'Brad Farkus',
  Picture: 'images/employees/50.png',
}, {
  ID: 49,
  Name: 'Jenny Hobbs',
  Picture: 'images/employees/48.png',
}, {
  ID: 50,
  Name: 'Dallas Lou',
  Picture: 'images/employees/41.png',
}, {
  ID: 51,
  Name: 'Stu Pizaro',
  Picture: '',
}];

const priorities: Priority[] = [
  { id: 1, value: 'Low' },
  { id: 2, value: 'Normal' },
  { id: 3, value: 'Urgent' },
  { id: 4, value: 'High' },
];

@Injectable()
export class Service {
  getTasks(): Task[] {
    return tasks.map((task: Task) => {
      employees.forEach((employee: Employee) => {
        if (task.Task_Assigned_Employee_ID === employee.ID) {
          task.Task_Assigned_Employee = employee;
        }
      });

      return task;
    });
  }

  getEmployees(): Employee[] {
    return employees;
  }

  getPriorities(): Priority[] {
    return priorities;
  }
}
```

To import a file from json in Angular project just import it by path:

```
import * as faMessages from './../assets/localization/fa.json';
```

And remember to add this config into `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "resolveJsonModule": true, // this one
```

Then loade the data from json in service